# XAuth with nodeJS

Tags: twitter, node.js, xauth

I want to know if there is any module for XAuth (general or for Twitter).  I try create a module for node.js but really piced off because one problem with the Headers (that can't resolve it).

Comment: Where have you looked so far?

Comment: only in the modules (wiki section) in the github of nodejs. But there isn't any for xauth. (only oauth).

Answer (score 0):

there are at least three different implementations available. [wiki/modules](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#security) is your best resource.

Comment: Can you read my question again?. I need module for XAuth no for OAuth. In the modules wiki section there is only modules for OAuth.

Comment: First line on twitter's xAuth docs: **xAuth is still OAuth**. You just need a few extra parameters. I've written an oAuth client with jsdb, you could probably extend it to support xAuth easily (just ignore the messed up code structure): https://github.com/ricardobeat/clit/blob/master/main.js

Comment: I make my own xAuth module for nodejs about 2 weeks later. Thanks anyway! :D

Comment: are you shared your xauth module ?